# Using Dynamic Value to add Object to Array with the Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some code within a function that looks like this:

```
 const updatedItemsArr = [...this.state.targetItems, {relationship: value}];
```

What I want to do is pass in a dynamic value in place of `relationship`. However, whatever I try ends up causing an error or is incorrect syntax.

This will not work:

```
const fieldType = 'relationship';
const updatedItemsArr = [...this.state.targetItems, {fieldType: value}];
```

Nor will this:

```
  const updatedItemsArr = [...this.state.targetItems, {`${fieldType}`: value}];
```

How can I pass in a dynamic value here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES6 what you can do is you can put the dynamic key inside brackets. So

```
const updatedItemsArr = [...this.state.targetItems, {[fieldType]: value}];
```

should work.

Comment: It works like a charm, better than my solution, so if you can use ES6 this is preferred.

Comment: While it indeed works, it is basically repeating what is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327). It is discouraged to answer questions that are already answered on Stack Overflow. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) (Users above 15 reputation and below 3000 reputation [can flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) questions as duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
const dynObj = {};
dynObj[fieldType] = value;  
const updatedItemsArr = [...this.state.targetItems, dynObj];
```